# Kernel flashing needs data wipe. Why?

Tags: factory-reset, kernel, google-pixel-6a

Pixel 6a running stock Android 13

There are very few custom kernels available for this device. I found a couple of kernels that I would like to try but here comes the caveat -it needs a [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset).

This was surprising as on my Pixel 4a (also on Android 13), there was no such restriction.

Developers didn't bother to give any reason, so I thought of asking here.

What is the reason for this?

PS: Kernels here [Dark kernel](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/kernel-13-official-bluejay-darkkernel-march-3-2023.4541711/), [Azure Telegram](https://t.me/azure_pixels)

Comment: Is it because dm-verity is not disabled using `fastboot flash --disable-verity vbmeta vbmeta.img` ?